# How to get "python http.server" to work in Arch Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, archlinux

When I enter "python http.server" I expect to get the simple webserver, instead I get:

```
$ python http.server
python: can't open file 'http.server': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

While on my server, also an Arch box (has been running for some time so unclear what packages are installed) this command does run the webserver.

What am I missing?

Edit: Yes, off course, the "-m", I'm sorry for wasting time but thanx for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Python 3 this will run the server listening on port `9000`.

```
$  python3 -m http.server 9000
```

Answer (score 4):

For Python2, I believe the command you are looking for is

```
 python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

If you have python3, then [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) suggests that you need

```
 python3 -m http.server
```